# Delegate Property for UIApplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

So I am starting to learn Core Data for iOS and have wrote this section of code out:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    id delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *objectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Album"];
    //An array of our sorted Album objects by date in ascending order
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *fetchedAlbums = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    self.albums = [fetchedAlbums mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

My question is what is the purpose of this line:

```
id delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

I know for a fact that for a delegate you need to pass in the current instance of a specific object to the delegate property which sets that object as the delegate for the other object. My question here is when you do:

```
id delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

which object is being passed in to that `delegate` property? The `sharedApplication` method returns a singleton instance of the app I am assuming and then you are getting the `delegate` property for that single instance of the app. Is that delegate referring to the same one being used in the `AppDelegate.h`/`AppDelegate.m` files?

And if that delegate property is the same one that is being used in `AppDelegate.h`/`AppDelegate.m` files shouldn't there be a line of code in the `AppDelegate.m` file in the `viewDidLoad` method where we be pass in the current instance of the `AppDelegate.m` in the delegate property, similar to what we do for a `tableView`:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self.
```

I don't see where that is done for the `delegate` property in this line:

```
id delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Comment: You are getting the delegate, not setting it.

Comment: Oh ok, but what object or instance is passed into that delegate property that we are getting? Is it the current instance of the AppDelegate.m file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to assign your `AppDelegate` as a delegate for your application because it is being automatically done for you.

In objective-c you can look at main.m function where you can find the mentioning of you `AppDelegate` class:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

After this call the system will set the instance of class `AppDelegate` as a delegate for your application.

In Swift, main.m is missing which is why you always have `@UIApplicationMain` before the declaration of your delegate class:

```
@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
}
```

Because `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` is a singleton, `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` always returns the same instance of `AppDelegate`.

So, if you modify some property in your `AppDelegate` from one view controller you can be sure that the other view controllers will have access to the modified version. You can easily verify it yourself by implementing a simple counter and checking that you always can read the latest value :)

Comment: OHH, amazing explanation Andriy... Thank you so much! Regarding your post I have one more quick question. I noticed that the method: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); takes four arguments. Why is the third argument set to nil? I understand that the last argument is basically saying which class should the delegate be set to, but what does the third argument specify?

Comment: @GarryHarry third argument is the PrincipalClass name. Passing nil defaults to UIApplication :) You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/ . As to the function - you have main.m in your project as well. Search for it in the file inspector

Comment: Hey Andriy! Thanks for the quick response. I just looked at the class reference and it made much more sense now. Also sorry if I am asking too much, but what are the values argc and argv parameters that are passing in the UIApplicationMain function? I have coded in C in college, and when you run your .c file in terminal using gcc you specify your argv by passing in the files on terminal and then in your .c file you can do something like check if (argc == somenumber) then do something? Is there any way you can figure out what is being passed in to the argv?

Comment: @GarryHarry as you see, it passes through the variables which it gets when the function is called by the system. I think you might be able to log them with NSLog :)

Comment: Oh arite, I will try that! Thanks for the suggestions... helped me out a lot!